# PHP and Graphics Magick on MacOSX after brew installing

Tags: php, macos, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to switch to GraphicsMagick from Imagick, because I read it was better for performance if you don't need a lot of the fancy options that come with IMagick. I was able to install it via:

```
brew install graphicsmagick
```

After it was installed I'm trying to use it:

```
use GMagick;

$image = new GMagick($request->file('banner_image')->path());
$image->resizeimage(600,600, Gmagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1)
```

Seeing error:

```
Class 'GMagick' not found
```

Added the extension to php.ini with this:

```
extension=gmagick.so
```

Restarted apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Nothing works....can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: try to `sudo killall httpd` ... if El-Capitan+ ... LaunchControl should restart it nicely. just a guess :) ... and check with phpinfo + logs to see if the lib actually loads properly. If it did not, i suspect you may have to be 'very' specific on the path

Comment: when i search this mac for gmagick.so it is not found, but when i run brew install graphicsmagick it returns Warning: graphicsmagick-1.3.25 already installed

Comment: look for it in `/usr/local/opt` or under `/usr/local/Cellar` ... prefer opt if you find it, hardwiring (Cellar) is *almost* never a good plan.

Comment: the folder is there, but no gmagick.so anywhere. /usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick

Comment: oh darn , you should specify you use MAMP on your questions. Good luck.

Comment: I actually don't use MAMP for this project, I'm using the native PHP. Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini

Comment: that path corresponds to a brew php install. What happens if you `php -v` at the command line ?

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.22/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gmagick.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.22/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gmagick.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick search and found that you can brew `php56-gmagick` ... probably the one you wanted. Try to uninstall your `graphicsmagick` and brew the one i suggest here. I just installed for php55 without a glitch. If you run `php -m` you should see the `gmagick` extension loaded successfully (did for me).

ps. Dont forget to restart your apache to get access from http sessions running php scripts.

pps. If you run php-fpm, restart that too :)

Comment: Worked! Thanks alot!